# The multi-part identifier " [column name ] " could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I 'm getting below error when executing the following update query.

Query:

```
update a
set 
   a.COURIER_STATUS='Acknowledge1',
   COURIER_ACK=1,
   COURIER_ACK_DATE=try_convert(datetime,b.[Crown_Inward_Date]),
   b.status = 'Processed', 
   b.processed_date = getdate()
from ONE_LMS a
join upload b on a.GROUP_ID=b.GR_NO and a.LAN_ID=b.[Loan_AC] and b.status is null
```

Error Message:

> The multi-part identifier "b.status" could not be bound.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A DML statement can effect **one** object, not two. You're trying to update `ONE_LMS` and `upload`.

Comment: On a different note, there's no `a` in  `ONE_LMS` and no `b` on `upload`. Have a read of [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). Good, and consistent, aliases is really important for readable code.

Comment: Ok got it..I have to use two update queries...Thanks @larnu

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use with two update query**

```
update a
    set 
       a.COURIER_STATUS='Acknowledge1',
       COURIER_ACK=1,
       COURIER_ACK_DATE=try_convert(datetime,b.[Crown_Inward_Date]),
       b.status = 'Processed', 
       b.processed_date = getdate()
    from ONE_LMS a
    join upload b on a.GROUP_ID=b.GR_NO and a.LAN_ID=b.[Loan_AC] and b.status is null


    update b
    set 
       b.status = 'Processed', 
       b.processed_date = getdate()
    from ONE_LMS a
    join upload b on a.GROUP_ID=b.GR_NO and a.LAN_ID=b.[Loan_AC] and b.status is null
```